# How do I leave a trail behind a sprite with pygame? (Tron Game)

Tags: python, pygame

My partner and I have been working on this Tron game, but we have gotten stuck on add a trail behind the 2 squares. We have looked through other forms and haven't gotten and good information, if anyone can look at this code and help up get a trail it will be greatly appreciated.

We are making a Tron game. If one of the opponents run into their own or oppositions trail they die and the other wins.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (K_i, K_k, K_j, K_l, K_ESCAPE, K_w, K_a, K_d, K_s, KEYDOWN, QUIT,)

p1_movement = 0
p2_movement = 0

pygame.init()   

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
green = (0,255,0)

WIDTHTWO = 1
HEIGHTTWO = 1000
WIDTHONE = 2000
HEIGHTONE = 1000

pygame.display.set_caption("Tron")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(60)
screen.fill((0,0,0))

class PlayerOne(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   p1_movement = 0
   def __init__(self):
       super(PlayerOne, self).__init__()
       self.surf = pygame.Surface((15, 10))
       self.surf.fill((255, 0, 0))
       self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = (WIDTHONE / 2, HEIGHTONE / 2)

   def update(self, pressed_keys):
       if pressed_keys[K_i]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
       if pressed_keys[K_k]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
       if pressed_keys[K_j]:
           self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
       if pressed_keys[K_l]:
           self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
           
       if self.rect.left < 0:
          self.rect.left = 0
       if self.rect.right > 1000:
          self.rect.right = 1000
       if self.rect.top <= 0:
          self.rect.top = 0
       if self.rect.bottom >= 1000:
          self.rect.bottom = 1000  
          
          

class PlayerTwo(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   p1_movement = 0
   def __init__(self):
       super(PlayerTwo, self).__init__()
       self.surf = pygame.Surface((15, 10))
       self.surf.fill((0, 255, 255))
       self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = (WIDTHTWO / 2, HEIGHTTWO / 2)

   def update(self, pressed_keys):
       if pressed_keys[K_w]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
       if pressed_keys[K_s]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
       if pressed_keys[K_a]:
           self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
       if pressed_keys[K_d]:
           self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
           
       if self.rect.left < 0:
          self.rect.left = 0
       if self.rect.right > 1000:
          self.rect.right = 1000
       if self.rect.top <= 0:
          self.rect.top = 0
       if self.rect.bottom >= 1000:
          self.rect.bottom = 1000    
    
    
player = PlayerOne()
playertwo = PlayerTwo()
running = True

while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
               running = False       
       elif event.type == QUIT:
           running = False

   pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
   
   player.update(pressed_keys)
   playertwo.update(pressed_keys)
   screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
   screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
   screen.blit(playertwo.surf, playertwo.rect)
   pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: There are many ways to draw a "trail" behind a sprite. Most common way is to keep track of previous x,y coordinates of sprite and show increasingly transparent copies of the sprite

Comment: @Gillespie,  good idea, but I think in this case the trail does not fade out.  It is a barrier that the players cannot run into.  You probably haven't seen the Tron movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `pygame.draw.lines`.
This method will take in a list of coordinates, and connect the dots.

How would we construct the list of coordinates?
Simply as `self.trail = []` to the `__init__` function to store the coordinates,
and append the coordinates to the list in the `update()` functions.

So in the `update()` functions, add `self.trail.append(self.rect.center)`:

```
pos = self.rect.center
if self.trail:
   if self.trail[-1] != pos:
       self.trail.append(pos)
else:
   self.trail = [pos, pos]
```

and in the main game loop, add the `pygame.draw.lines` parts.

**Full working code:**

```
from pygame.locals import (K_i, K_k, K_j, K_l, K_ESCAPE, K_w, K_a, K_d, K_s, KEYDOWN, QUIT,)
import pygame

p1_movement = 0
p2_movement = 0

pygame.init()   

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
green = (0,255,0)

WIDTHTWO = 1
HEIGHTTWO = 1000
WIDTHONE = 2000
HEIGHTONE = 1000

pygame.display.set_caption("Tron")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(60)
screen.fill((0,0,0))

class PlayerOne(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   p1_movement = 0
   def __init__(self):
       super(PlayerOne, self).__init__()
       self.surf = pygame.Surface((15, 10))
       self.surf.fill((255, 0, 0))
       self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = (WIDTHONE / 2, HEIGHTONE / 2)
       self.trail = []

   def update(self, pressed_keys):
       if pressed_keys[K_i]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
       if pressed_keys[K_k]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
       if pressed_keys[K_j]:
           self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
       if pressed_keys[K_l]:
           self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
       pos = self.rect.center
       if self.trail:
           if self.trail[-1] != pos:
               self.trail.append(pos)
       else:
           self.trail = [pos, pos]
       if self.rect.left < 0:
          self.rect.left = 0
       if self.rect.right > 1000:
          self.rect.right = 1000
       if self.rect.top <= 0:
          self.rect.top = 0
       if self.rect.bottom >= 1000:
          self.rect.bottom = 1000  
          
          

class PlayerTwo(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   p1_movement = 0
   def __init__(self):
       super(PlayerTwo, self).__init__()
       self.surf = pygame.Surface((15, 10))
       self.surf.fill((0, 255, 255))
       self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = (WIDTHTWO / 2, HEIGHTTWO / 2)
       self.trail = set()

   def update(self, pressed_keys):
       if pressed_keys[K_w]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
       if pressed_keys[K_s]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
       if pressed_keys[K_a]:
           self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
       if pressed_keys[K_d]:
           self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
       pos = self.rect.center
       if self.trail:
           if self.trail[-1] != pos:
               self.trail.append(pos)
       else:
           self.trail = [pos, pos]
       if self.rect.left < 0:
          self.rect.left = 0
       if self.rect.right > 1000:
          self.rect.right = 1000
       if self.rect.top <= 0:
          self.rect.top = 0
       if self.rect.bottom >= 1000:
          self.rect.bottom = 1000    
    
    
player = PlayerOne()
playertwo = PlayerTwo()
running = True

while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
               running = False       
       elif event.type == QUIT:
           running = False

   pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
   
   player.update(pressed_keys)
   playertwo.update(pressed_keys)
   screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
   pygame.draw.lines(screen, (255, 255, 255), False, player.trail)
   pygame.draw.lines(screen, (255, 255, 255), False, playertwo.trail)
   screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
   screen.blit(playertwo.surf, playertwo.rect)
   pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute `rect_list` to the class `PalyereOne` and `append` a copy of the current rectangle to the list when the player is moved:

```py
class PlayerOne(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   p1_movement = 0
   def __init__(self):
       # [...]

       self.rect_list = []

   def update(self, pressed_keys):
       self.rect_list.append(self.rect.copy())

       # [...]
```

Draw the list of rectangles in the main application loop:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    for rect in player.rect_list:
        screen.blit(player.surf, rect)

    # [...]
```

Do the same for `PlayerTwo`.

Comment: Hey i have done that to both. but its only working for the red side why is that?